# Prove $f(x)$ differentiable at the origin

Tags: limits, derivatives

$$
f(x) = \cases{ x^2\sin(1/x) & if $x \neq 0$ \\
      0 & if $x = 0$}
$$
justify that $f(x)$ is differentiable at the origin using
$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$

Comment: Did you try using the limit? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Why don't you investigate the limit? Hint: put $x=0$ in the formula you gave.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=h \sin(1/h)$, hence

$|\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}| \le |h|$.

What can you say about $ \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$x^2\sin(1/x)=x\times\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{(\frac{1}{x})}$$

Now try using limit $x \to 0$

Comment: We are not trying to show that the limit of $f$ as $x\to 0$ is $0$, but rather that the function is differentiable at the origin.